# Swapping information on click and hide other's info angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is jsfiddle [Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/amanjoshi/m6ykxtrt/4/)

I created first time in fiddle don't know why it is say myApp is not define please change the same.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrlr">
        <div class="userAssign" ng-repeat="user in children">

                            <br>
                            <span class="main-header-cardion">
                              <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="" ng-click="swapUser(user.user_id);" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                              <span ng-if="user.type == '2'">{{user.first_name}}</span>
                              <span ng-if="user.type == '3'">{{user.name}}</span>
                            </a>
                            </span>


<section class="accordion1" ng-show="state && parentUser.user_id == user.user_id">
    {{user.age}}
    {{user.height}}          
</section>

</div>

    </div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrlr', ['$scope',function($scope){

     $scope.children = [
       {
            "first_name" : "Alfreds",
            "last_name" : "Futterkiste",
            "name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
            "age" : "50",
            "height" : "5",
            "type" : "2",
            "user_id" : "1"
        },{
            "first_name" : "John",
            "last_name" : "Futterkiste",
            "name" : "John Futterkiste",
            "age" : "50",
            "height" : "5",
            "type" : "2",
            "user_id" : "2"
        },{
            "first_name" : "Jimmy",
            "last_name" : "Futterkiste",
            "name" : "Jimmy Futterkiste",
            "age" : "50",
            "height" : "5",
            "type" : "3",
            "user_id" : "3"
        },{
            "first_name" : "Shekh",
            "last_name" : "Futterkiste",
            "name" : "Shekh Futterkiste",
            "age" : "50",
            "height" : "5",
            "type" : "3",
            "user_id" : "4"
        }

];
$scope.last_element = $scope.children[$scope.children.length - 1];
$scope.parentUser = $scope.last_element;
$scope.swapUser = function swapUser(user_id)
        {

            $scope.children.filter(function(item){
                if(item.user_id == user_id)
                {
                    $scope.state = !$scope.state;
                    $scope.currentSetUser = user_id;
                                return $scope.parentUser = item;
                }
            });
        }

}]);
```

Expected : Intially opens the first anchor values and then when we click on rest it should open immediate and close rest.

Currently what's happening when i click one it show the details when i click next to link it hides first value thereafter click it show the value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly the issue, do you want to open the details when clicking on one option and if there is any other option opened then close it?

Comment: correct please see fiddle for the same

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qzkgjjzo/5/ apply this logic

Comment: You have to remove the 'state' in the `ng-show` (and also inside the swapUser function) because every time you click on an anchor you change the value between false/true, so if an anchor is showing its details 'state = true', but if you click on other anchor, state will be false so you will have 'ng-show=false'